# On an inequality inspired in the definition of strong primes and the Firoozbakht's conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures

The idea of next puzzle arises from a combination of the definition of the so-called strong primes and the Firoozbakht's conjecture. You can find the inequality defining strong primes in number theory from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_prime#Definition_in_number_theory) and the Firoozbakht's conjecture from [1] or well from this [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture)

On assumption of the Firoozbakht's conjecture one has that strong primes $p_{n+1}$ satisfy the inequality

$$1+\frac{p_{n+2}}{p_{n}}<2(p_n)^{1/n}.\tag{1}$$

**Computational fact.** Seems that there are finitely many primes $p_n$ satisfying $$1+\frac{p_{n+2}}{p_{n}}<\sqrt{3}\cdot p_n^{1/n}.$$
 You can see such evidence if you this code

`for (i = 1, 10000,if (1+prime(i+2)/prime(i)<sqrt(7/2)*(prime(i))^(1/i),print(prime(i))))`

in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) (choose *GP* as language and press *Evaluate*). Notice that you can to write $3$ isntead of $7/2$ inside the square root function.

Thus using the inequalities from the literature for the size of the $n$th prime number should be easy to prove it.$\square$

My belief is that the following conjecture inspired in previous remarks is true.

**Conjecture.** *For each fixed integer* $l\geq 0$ *there exist finitely many prime numbers that we denote with* $P_n$ *satisfying the inequality* $$1+\frac{P_{n+2}}{P_{n}}<\sqrt{3+\frac{2^{l+1}-1}{2^{l+1}}}\cdot P_n^{1/n}.\tag{2}$$

> **Question.** Can you to prove or refute previous conjecture? **Many thanks.**

I am asking about to prove unconditionally, or refute previous conjecture about prime numbers.

### References:

[1] Farideh Firoozbakht, Conjecture 30. The Firoozbakht Conjecture, The Prime Puzzles & Problems Connection, by Carlos Rivera (22 August 2012).

Comment: The conjecture looks a lot like $\downarrow$ *Andrica’s Conjecture* by the way. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture

Comment: Do you think that it is 
essentially the same? I am saying because obviously the credit of such conjecture is due to Andrica, and then I should delete my post @user477343

Comment: That’s why I said *by the way*. I wanted to show something that might be related. It’s an interesting topic so don’t delete the post.

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand English expressions very well, many thanks for your remarks and help @user477343 . I am wait to see what are saying the users.

Comment: Hahah, no problem. I didn’t mean to bring forward any offence :)

Comment: No please, I am saying I'm sorry to you, the problem is mine (to me it's impossible to understand English) @user477343

Comment: @user243301 I think that your second conjecture is very difficult to decide, the first is an open problem, isn't it ? If the bounds for the $n$-th prime would already decide the first conjecture, I think this would have been done already.

Comment: If you are content with a good heuristic for your second conjecture, I am optimistic that someone finds it. But a rigorous proof is something else!

Comment: Many thanks @Peter I think that the conjecture in the section Computational fact, should be feasible to get. Well, I hope that the magic of this site  MSE works on my Question.